# process for creating outbond messaging

Tags: integration, workflowoutboundmessage

I am looking to send outbound message from my sf instance with to dell boomi server, i Have the required endpoint URL. Do I need to create any web service class or any sort of integration process is needed to acheive this or I can simply put the URl and Fields in the workflow's outbound message and it'll work? Please suggest

Comment: Webservice not needed

Comment: Please check the this link if it helps https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_setting_up.htm